# Laravel Capsule: Catch PDOException

Tags: php, database, laravel, exception

I'm building a gateway to enable several instances of an application to communicate with each other. To connect to the different databases I'm using Laravel's Capsule.

When the request on a database fails I would like to log the error however for some reason I am unable to catch the exception properly. Looking at the logs the catch is working however after that the application is still dying.

The code is pretty basic:

```
try {
    // connection and request here
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    Log::error('*************************************************************************');
    Log::error('Failure reading franchise BDCs');
    Log::error('Franchise: '.json_encode($franchise->site_url));
    Log::error('*************************************************************************');
}
```

In the logs I have the following:

> [2015-04-29 09:46:35] production.INFO: Started reading PPFD [] []
>
> [2015-04-29 09:46:35] production.ERROR:
>
> ************************************************************************* [] []
>
> [2015-04-29 09:46:35] production.ERROR: Failure reading franchise BDCs [] []
>
> [2015-04-29 09:46:35] production.ERROR: Franchise: "https://ppfd.domain.net/" [] []
>
> [2015-04-29 09:46:35] production.ERROR:
>
> ************************************************************************* [] []
>
> [2015-04-29 09:46:35] production.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'pp.damain.net' (using password: YES)' in /var/www/fd/releases/20150423164018/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
>
> Stack trace:

How can I catch this exception and allow the code to carry on instead of crashing?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Laravel 4.1, never got round to upgrading that particular application

Answer (score 0):

```
App::error(function(PDOException $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors

Comment: During the process I'm reading from multiple databases. I need the process to continue instead of stopping if one of the database connections fail.

Comment: @xonorageous sorry, missed that. See updated answer.